# Can't send email with MailGun on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mailgun

I'm attempting to send an email with Mailgun in production in my Rails app, but I can only send it to 'Authorized Recipients' (i.e. myself). This makes me think that I'm still using my Sandbox domain somehow.

So far I've:

- Taken the steps [here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#verify-your-domain) to verify my domain. In my account on Mailgun I see 'Verified' next to my domain, and I've got green checkmarks next to the two TXT files in the 'Domain Verification & DNS' section.
- Updated my `environment.rb` and `production.rb` files to include my domain.

One potentially important note is that I'm using a custom domain, rather than the `myapp.heroku.com` domain.

What else do I need to update to get this to work?

Comment: Check for delivery errors by `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true `

Comment: The answers in the thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534567/verified-email-not-sending-through-heroku-mailgun) ended up solving my problem.